# The "canon" and "canon-eos" tags?

Tags: discussion, tag-naming

We have both `[canon]` and `[canon-eos]` tags. Is it preferable to leave these as they are, or reduce the canon-eos tag to simply `[eos]`, and use it with the `[canon]` tag?

UPDATE:

I've removed the canon-eos tag, as it was redundant and generally not useful.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, so far camera models is mostly used with the camera name, like `[canon-g11]`, which makes sense. I see some exceptions where both exist, like `[canon-t2i]` and `[t2i]`, which should probably be retagged after we decide what the format should be.

The EOS term is however a bit different, as it applies to all Canon SLRs, both to digital and film cameras, so it's mostly equivalent to the `[canon]` `[slr]` combination. As it's so wide, it's not very useful, especially as most qustions that relate to cameras in the EOS series won't be tagged with it. Perhaps the `[canon-eos]` tag shouldn't exist at all.

Comment: Isn't the EOS line only DSLR? Or does it also apply to the film SLR line as well?

Comment: I think the eos line started before the switch to digital... the Elan I think?

Comment: @jrista: I had an EOS 1000FN, then an EOS 300 before getting my first DSLR. Now the only remaining SLR in the product line is the EOS-1v.